# Byte class is not working in Generics in java

Tags: java

My code is:-

```
class abc<T> {
    T a, b;
    abc(T p, T q) {
        a = p;
        b = q;
    }
    void disp() {
        System.out.println("\na = " + a);
        System.out.println("b = " + b);
        System.out.println("a/b is of class type : " + a.getClass().getName());
    }
}

class temp {
    public static void main(String...args) {
        abc<Integer> a1;
        a1 = new abc <Integer>(11, 22);
        abc<Byte> a2 = new abc <Byte>(50,5);
        a1.disp();
        a2.disp();
    }
}
```

OUTPUT:-

```
temp.java:23: cannot find symbol
symbol  : constructor abc(int,int)
location: class abc<java.lang.Byte>
            abc <Byte> a2 = new abc <Byte> (50,5);
                            ^
1 error
```

Please help me out in this question. I am new to java, so learning about generics.

In this code wen I used Integer, Float, Double, String all were working fine but when I get to Byte class the compiler throws an error.

Comment: Welcome to Java. The Java convention for class names is to start with an uppercase letter, so `Abc` . This makes it easier for others to read your code

Answer (score 6, accepted):

How about this?

```
abc <Byte> a2 = new abc <Byte> ((byte)50, (byte)5);
```

The parameters you provide as numeric literals are of type integer, and those are automatically boxed to java.lang.Integer and that's why a corresponding method is not initially found unless you explicitly say that your literals are of type byte.